# Is any C++20 feature test for defaulted equal operator?

Tags: c++, operators, c++20

I wanted to use defaulted equal operator `bool operator ==(...) = default;` if only compiler supports it, otherwise I could still use existing implementation.

But I cannot find an appropriate feature test in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test

Point me the correct feature test or help to fix this code:

```
struct Some {
  constexpr bool operator == (const Some& rhs) const noexcept 
#if __cpp_what?
   = default;
#else
   {
      ...
   }
#endif
};
```

Comment: Maybe `__cpp_lib_three_way_comparison` and/or `__cpp_impl_three_way_comparison` as this requires that they can be created by default. So if the tree way comparison is there it might be likely that the default comparisons for the others might be too.

Comment: @t.niese you are right - this check works for my case. Probably there is nothing more "narrowed".

Comment: Not sure if that can be considered as reliable. But that's the only check that currently comes up to my mind.

Comment: So you want to target compilers with partial support of C++20, which do support feature testing, but may or may not support default specifier for operators? Seems... oddly specific.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen e.g. gcc9 and gcc10 differs in this case. I also used various versions of clang in my project. So, yes - I need this.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That's not "oddly specific" - that's literally the point of feature testing. So that you can target compilers with partial support, but know which features they support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As default comparison is tightly connected to

- [P1186R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1186r3.html): When do you actually use `<=>`?

you may be able make use of the `__cpp_impl_three_way_comparison` feature test also for the subset case of default comparison. See also [P1185R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html) (*`<=> != ==`*).

Answer (score 2):

The document you're looking for is [SD-FeatureTest](https://wg21.link/sd6). It ties in all the proposals and all the history of all the macro values.

Defaulted comparison is slightly unique in this sense, in that while it is a language feature, there is also a strong library component to it: in order to use `<=>`, you need to `#include <compare>` and use the comparison types defined in that header. As such, there are two macros here:

- `__cpp_impl_three_way_comparison`
- `__cpp_lib_three_way_comparison`

The language macro is really intended for the *standard library* to provide the library facility only when the compiler can support it.

The library macro is the one intended for the user (i.e., you) to use.

Comment: but for operator== I do not need library support, do I?

Comment: And in the table from the provided link - I see __cpp_impl_three_way_comparison connected to ==, so how can I get from this doc that I really need __cpp_lib_three_way_comparison ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations#language-features-with-library-components

Comment: @PiotrNycz You don't need library support, but it's all part of the same feature as `<=>`.